# Changing color of cell based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please advise how I can change color of cell D if column B contains names such as B2 = Mary, B3 = Mary etc and column D has percentages such 20%, 30% and if total percentage for all cells in column B containing Mary is not 100% it should color D cells in different color

I tried the below code and it's wrong:

```
    For w = 3 To 5318

    If .Formula = "=SUMIF($B:$B,$B2,$D:$D)<>1" = True Then

        Range("D" & w).ColorIndex = 3

    End If

    Next
```

Thanks

Comment: why not use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be in a macro, you should reference the interior:

```
Range("D" & w).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
```